# WCF Session Instancing Mode Hosting Issue

Tags: wcf, session, concurrency, load-balancing

I am facing a situation regarding hosting WCF on Session Instancing mode.I am encapsulating the actual situation and proposing an example to replicate it...as below.

The service to be hosted is "MyService".  I am using windows service to host it..with http endpoint.
It will need to support 500 concurrent sessions.(Singleton & Percall cannot be done because the Contract is Workflow based...Login...Function1,Function2,Logout..)
I have 4 Servers each with a hardware capability of supporting 200 concurrent sessions.
So I configured the service on One server as a Router(ServiceHost S = new ServiceHost(RouterService)) with hosting path such as "http://myserver/MyService".  I have set a simple load balancing mechanism and applied the Router table to redirect incoming requests to other three servers where the actual service copies are hosted...("http://myserver/MyService1","http://myserver/MyService2","http://myserver/MyService3")

It is still not working...As soon as hits go above 200...communication error starts...I suppose because when 500 concurrent calls are made, then the Router(capability 200) is also required to stay connected to the Client along with the Actual Service Server...(in Session Call mode)..Is my thinking correct??

My question is...

1) Is my approach correct or flawed from concept...Should I ask the Hardware team to set up NLB...
  2) Should we redesign the contract specifically to ensure that the requests can somehow be made PerCall...
  3) Someone suggested that such systems should be hosted on cloud (Windows Azure)...will need to look at costs involved...but is it correct...
  4) What are the best practicies involved while hosting WCF to handle Session Based Calls.

I understand that my question is complex and there would not be one "Correct" answer...but any help and insight will be really appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Should I ask the Hardware team to set up NLB..." as per you & "Sticky IP cluster" by Shiraz are the closest one can get to host the given scnerio.

The thing is that WCF sessions are transport based.hence we cannot store these "sessions" on a state server/db like a traditional aspnet.

WCF4.0 has come up with new bindings such as NetTcpContextBinding, BasicHttpContextBinding, WSHttpContextBinding which could help context re-creation on cross machine environment.But I have no production implementation knowledge to provide example.

[This](http://www.devproconnections.com/article/net-framework2/load-balancing-and-scaling-your-wcf-services-122258) article should help you to know more...

Answer (score 0):

There are three seperate but connected issues here:

- Your design requires that you maintain state between calls
- You are dependent upon getting to the same server each time (since you store state in memory)
- You have a limit of 200 connections per server

A solution where you are dependent on coming back to the same server will not work (well) on Windows Azure.

You could implement a Sticky IP cluster, that would solve most of your problems, but it would not guarrantee that no more than 200 connections are on one server. For the most part this would be OK.

You could store the cache in Appfabric Cache, then it would not matter which server you returned to.

You could redesign your system so that all state is stored in the database.